# scrolling event not triggering Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$(window).scroll(function()
        {
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
            {
                alert('d');
            }

        });
```

Is there any wrong with above code? I wish to do an infinite scrolling but stuck in the early phase. No error in my console I wonder why. It's working in pure js, but not in my Angularjs's controller.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jfzhwnty/1/

Comment: It is works: http://jsbin.com/sulosolifi/1/

Comment: Tangentially, I recommend testing for `>=` rather than `==` since you can actually scroll past the bottom of the page in some cases (OSX).